# Odoo - Change the grouping value in the pivot filter

Tags: pivot, pivot-table, filtering, grouping, odoo

Please see the picture I provided.

[pivot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9uJZ.png)

The data is grouped from 0 to 20 (eg the yellow one). But what I want to appear is not just 0, 1, 2, etc. I want to change it to something like "1M - 2M". Does anyone know how to do it?

So far I have created a method/function in the pivot report model. I've also tried using depends but it doesn't work. I've been working on it for 1 week, but I haven't found a solution. Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked into `read_group()` which is usually called when grouping data in Odoo views.

Comment: @Ori A stored computed field should work. If you are using an SQL view, you have just to change the field value in SELECT.

Comment: @Kenly computed field work, thank you.